# How to target a specific device in case a user has multiple devices (Push Notification)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush

I need to understand how to target a specific device in case a user has multiple devices via a push notification activity (journey builder).

I found this official SF article  [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_FAQ_product.htm)

Where they mention:

"You can target a specific device using device-level attributes combined with AMPscript. For example, you want to target only iOS devices or devices that haven’t enabled location sharing. Identify these characteristics using default attributes, such as platform, or customized tags or attributes. When you create a message, you can provide AMPscript that generates a message only to the intended device of a given user. For example:

```
%%[IF Platform == 'iPhone OS' THEN]%%Hello from Marketing Cloud!%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Does anyone know how this process works?

Where is the MC system referencing the Platform attribute?

I am aware the Platform attribute is a part of the _PushAddress data view. Is this AMPscript referencing this data view or the source DE used for the push send out? I am asking because if it's a source DE, we usually have one unique contact key in it (not duplicated contact keys and multiple unique device IDs per contact as it is under the _PushAddress data view). Thank you.