# Mobile Push Opt-out status update per deviceid

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, deliverability

Let me quickly describe, what issue we are facing.

The push notification messages delivery rate for our clients is currently 67%, which means that 33 % have bounced or are undeliverable due to various reasons. Either the client uninstalled the app or disabled push etc. Since we are going to be sending more and more push notifications, the total amount of bounced push notifications will rise and we don't want to rely on the automatic opt-out functionality in MC anymore (it's not reliable). Therefore, we have to optimize this.

I was thinking of deactivating push notifications on a device ID level. If the push notification bounces only once, I want to stop sending push notifications to this specific device. In other words, the idea is to opt-out device IDs under the _PushAddress data view. The problem is that it didn't work for me when I was testing it out.

I found a related documentation

- [LINK](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_import_contacts_best_practices.htm)

This article describes how to import users into MobilePush (I believe _PushAddress data view) and it also mentions the following:
"Import doesn't allow users to set the opt-out status of a device. But you can change the Marketer Status by mapping to the _Status field (either Active or Inactive)."

Do I understand correctly that it is actually possible to inactivate/opt out a certain device ID for a user (client/contact key) who has more devices?

If yes, how does it work? What is the "Marketer Status", and what is the name of the _Status field inside the _PushAddress data view? Based on the actual data view, it's a numeric value.

I was trying to find any option that would help to optimize this process, therefore I also posted a question on the possibility of targeting only specific devices based on certain criteria ([Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/410862/how-to-target-a-specific-device-in-case-a-user-has-multiple-devices-push-notifi)).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The "Status" attribute value should be "Active" or "Inactive", but the result value in the _PushAddress data view for the status attribute will be "1" indicating "active" or "2" inactive.

I also tested it out with some push send-outs. When the status is inactive (2), the device is not used in push notification sends. When the status is active  (1), the push is successfully sent.